# How to stop the scroll when an image goes off screen

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I have a fourteen column and a two column, in the two column i have an image with padding-left:70px.. when the image starts going off screen you can then scroll right and see the rest of the image showing the white gap its fallen into.. is there a way of stopping this so you will not see where the image has gone.. i know i have my width set to 100% on header its in.

```
    <div class="two columns">
    <img src="images/van2.png" class="van2image">
    </div>
    .van2image{
    padding-left:70px;
    }
```

If anyone could help me that would be great thanks.

Comment: just quickly put it together on JSFiddle here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/3oj3jxnp/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `overflow` property of the parent element to `hidden`. Provided you set a size for the parent in some form (implicit or explicit) the content should then be clipped.

```
.two.colums {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I applied the overflow:hidden to .two.columns{ and its now removed the image letting me see a tiny bit of it, its stopped the scrolling though which is what i wanted just now can't see the image. I haven't set the parent for it though.

Comment: Got a JSFiddle example to fully illustrate your situation?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3oj3jxnp/ there you go, test the browser at different sizes to see the scroll of the page bit

Comment: It would be easier to read the code if it was indented properly - such things plays a big difference in understanding the code.
Also, the HTML isn't valid: `<img src="images/van2.png" height="144" width="242"> class="van2image">`
Could you please review your code and make sure the markup is valid and indented correctly?

Comment: sorry i just quickly pasted code into jsfiddle hence why it was messy, also i have only put the height and width in on jsfiddle as on my site i don't need to as i have my image 100%. I will recheck it all once i finish work thanks

Answer (score 0):

To disable scrolling on the horizontal (x) axis:

```
.van2image{
    padding-left:70px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

To disable scrolling on the vertical (y) axis:

```
.van2image{      
    padding-left:70px; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

To disable scrolling on the x AND y axis:

```
.van2image{      
    padding-left:70px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work for me :/ was hoping it would be something easy like that

Comment: @DannyR Please add a jsfiddle

Comment: okies here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3oj3jxnp/

see when your browser is full screen image fits in correctly, then move it smaller and smaller.. you will be able to scroll off the page and see the white gap.